# jQuery if page is loaded and time passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Heyo,

I just want a simple if statement that checks if the whole page is loaded `window.loaded` and if a sertan amount of seconds have passed `time.passed`. I don't want to start the time.passed counter when the window is loaded ... i just want an if statement that checks if window && time is true.

Is that possible?

Here's my incorrect dream Code

```
if (window.loaded == true && time.passed == 3000) {
    // do something
}
```

I guess I have to work with variables and I'm fine with that ... I just don't know how to make it work for me.

Comment: In other words, Do you want to calculate page load time?

Comment: This is for a Preloader and if the site is loaded but the animation of the Preloader isn't finished yet it should still show up. Thats why i need the window.load && time.passed

Answer (score 1):

```js
var isLoadedAndTimePassed = false;

function run() {
  isLoadedAndTimePassed = true;
  console.log('loaded and time passed');
}

var time = (new Date()).getMilliseconds(), 
    wait = 3000;

window.addEventListener('load', function load() {
  window.removeEventListener('load', load);
  time = (new Date()).getMilliseconds() - time;
  if (time < wait) {
    window.setTimeout(run, wait - time);
  } else {
    run();
  }
});
```

Comment: correction: this doesn't work if the window takes longer to load then the timer set. If the window loaded the timer starts counting from that point on (which is not what i was looking for)

Comment: No, timer will not start if loading time is too long.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @NoSkill I figured out the answere myself. Even tought his script didn't work as intended I used it and rewrote it in jQuery. Now it works as I want it to.

I've added a little counter at the top to see if the script works as intended. I've also added a big image to make the site load a bit longer but for some reason in this Snippet-Tool the image loads instantly for me at least.

Here's the code:

```js
// counter to check if the script works as intended
var startTime = new Date();
setInterval(function () {
  $('span').html("ms since the start: " + (new Date() - startTime));
}, 100);

// the actual script
function run() {
  $('p').html('site loaded and 15s passed');
}    

var time = new Date(), 
    wait = 15000;

$(window).load(function(){
    var currenttime = new Date() - time;
    if (currenttime < wait) { setInterval(run, wait - currenttime); }
    else { run(); console.log(currenttime); }
});
```

```css
img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<span></span>
<p></p>
<img src="https://effigis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Airbus_Pleiades_50cm_8bit_RGB_Yogyakarta.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```